# Vue.js - Children to children component communication

Tags: javascript, scope, components, vue.js

I'm currently working with Vue.js for a project of mine. I'm using the component system and I'm not in the position where I would really need the ability to have two children components (sharing the same parent) to communicate between each other.

In this particular case I basically only need to have one of the children read a variable in the other child.

I'm looking for a nice, clean way of achieving this. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

It would probably be possible to use this.$parent.$children... etc but I'm looking for a more clean way if possible.

Comment: If you put together an example, I can modify it for you as part of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend declaring the property in the parent and via `props` bind it two-way from the parent to the component that manages the value and bind it one-way from the parent to the component that needs to only read it.

Based on your provided fiddle here's an example of that:

http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/662/

Instead of sending messages, you let binding take care of the information transfer.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand what you suggest me to do. But if you feel like showing me on a real example feel free to do that. I have put together a quick and dirty example here: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/660/ 
You could maybe copy that fiddle to a new one where you make the changes.

Comment: I made a new version of the fiddle for vue 2 because the old one doesn't work anymore and the principle has changed
http://jsfiddle.net/9pgvu15f/